# ¿Qué tiempo se usaría en el lenguaje coloquial para decir "Si hubiera tenido dinero me hubiera gustado comprarle una dentadura postiza"?

Tags: subjuntivo

En la siguiente frase:

> Si hubiera tenido dinero me hubiera gustado comprarle una dentadura
>   postiza.

Según la RAE la alternancia (condicional vs. subjuntivo) de usar el  pretérito pluscuamperfecto del subjuntivo en las oraciones condicionales está permitida. Hablantes nativos: me podríais decir por favor ¿qué tiempo verbal usaríais en el lenguaje coloquial?

Gracias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yo me quedo con la forma *subjuntivo* + *condicional*. A saber, *si **hubiera/hubiese**..., **habría....***

Si bien en inglés, se adopta la forma que expuse, he escuchado a mucha gente ocupar la forma con subjuntivo en ambas cláusulas. Para algunos natural, para otros, no.

Answer (score 1):

Yo personalmente "conservo" la forma tradicional (a veces se me escapa "hubiera ... hubiera"), pero lo que oigo la mayoría de las veces es efectivamente "hubiera ... hubiera".